# Updating text font in combobox in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a part of the code. I want to show all fonts, which I have on my OS in combo box. Then names of fonts should look like a preview showing how each font looks. This is my code :

```
List<String> families = Font.getFamilies();
fontfamilies = FXCollections.observableArrayList(families);
comboBox.setItems(fontfamilies);
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);

comboBox.setCellFactory((ListView<String> listView) -> {
    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {
                setText(item);
                setFont(new Font(item, 12));
            }
        }
    };
    //cell.setPrefWidth(120);
    return cell;
});
```

But I get this error:

```
Error:(59, 20) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
javafx.scene.control.ListCell<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to javafx.scene.control.ListCell<capture#1 of ?>
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Please show how you defined `comboBox`

Comment: I definied like that :     @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> comboBox;

Comment: My fault, I haven't seen this before, should be ComboBox<String>

Comment: Excellent idea! The only thing missing is for the Selected Value of the ComboBox to be using the same font as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to how you defined your member variable `comboBox`, you defined it using [*wildcard*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) which represents **an unknown type** while the rest of your code expect `String` as `ComboBox`'s type.

So simply define it as next:

```
@FXML private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
```